# my login not working correctly.it shows an error of "The webpage has redirect loop" how can i resolve this?

Tags: php

I have a sample.php page and inside that sample.php page i have a login script.the problem is that everytime i try to login there a page dislaying that "The webpages has redirect loop", and i don't know how to fix it..can somebody please help me resolve this..

```
<?php
session_start();
$username="";

if(count($_POST)>0) {
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("region_survey",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survey_login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(is_array($row)) {
        $_SESSION["Survey_id"] = $row[Survey_id];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $row[username];
    } else {
        $username = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION["Survey_id"])) {
    header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Firts of all it's not reliable login system... you have to do something more secure...

Comment: aren't you missing quotes around the indexes? ex. $row['username']?

Comment: @kiyarash can you help me to make it more secure.please..because i really don't know how to fix it..

Comment: I wrote some suggestion here... check here and feel free to ask me if you hade a question . http://pastebin.com/rbJXJfQp

Comment: @MauricioTrajano i think i'm not missing something in my code..can you help me figure it out..

Comment: can somebody pleae help me edit my login script..please..

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to recheck your code logic...

user will fill out the login form with `username` and `password` and `submit` the form button...

The form values come to `form action attribute value` --> `target of form`

You will check your registered user table in your database to check if this user have right to access to your page

`if true` --> you'll save user session
`else` --> redirect user to login page

As much as I can understand from your code, you are fetching user data from database and save these in a session if the query has ressult... 
 May be it could work, but it's not a complete solution...

This a sample guideline :

```
session_start();
if( isset( $_POST['submitButtonName'] ) ) //means the form is submitted using submit button
{

$username = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['username'] )  ); //or something you need
$pass     = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['password'] )  ); //or something you need

$sql = 'select * from tablename where username = ' . $username . ' and password= ' . $pass . ' limit 1';

//create a connection to your DB using PHP PDO class which is more safe and reliable
$conn = new PDO('mysql: host = localhost; dbname = databaseName;', $DBUsername, $DBPass);
$conn->exec("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';");
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
$conn->exec("set names 'utf8';");


$sendQueryUsingPDO = $conn->query( $sql );

$fetchDataFromDb = $sendQueryUsingPDO->fetchColumn();

if( $fetchDataFromDb['username'] == $username && $fetchDataFromDb['password'] == $pass )
{

    //user is valid, write sessions and redirect it to  your target page

}// end of if

else
{

    //user is not valid and redirect it to login page and unset sessions

}//end of else

}//if user submit the form
```

I hope it could be a start point...

**UPDATE :**

As you asked in your comment, it's using `mysql` :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'yourDB';
$us = 'yourDB_Username';
$ps = 'yourDB_Password';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $us, $ps);
if (!$link) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
}
else
{
    echo 'Connected successfully';
}

mysql_select_db( $db, $link);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if( $row['username'] == $username  && $row['password'] == $pass )
{

    // user is valid

}

else
{

    //user is not valid

}
```

Comment: thanks man for the sample code..but can convert that code to mysql because i want to finish this first before i go to mysqli or PDO..

Comment: Of course I'll do it for you, but remember that the mysql functions are almost deprecated now and it's better to start using PDO... It's completely easy to use... you need about an hour to start PDO basics...

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql: host = localhost; dbname = databaseName; port= 3306` that will fail. Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: @Kiyarash thanks man..i know that mysql function will be deprecated. but i just want to finish it first because its almost done..the only problem left is my login..

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're right... I updated the answer... thanks for your attention...

Comment: `mysql: host = localhost; dbname = databaseName` it contains spaces, there should not be any. I.e.: `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName` just one of PDO's quirks.

Comment: but I copied this from my project code and it work for me...

Comment: must be the way your system is setup then. Using `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened may throw one.

Comment: could you please send me a link that i can learn more about this??? I used this in several remote and local systems and there wasn't kind of error yet?!?!?!

Comment: @kiyarash what about the session?

Comment: @kiyarash what about the session?

Comment: @kierkier What's wrong with session?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
if(isset($_SESSION["Survey_id"])) {
    header("Location:login.php");
}
```

to

```
if(isset($_SESSION["Survey_id"])) {
    unset($_SESSION["Survey_id"]);
    header("Location:login.php");
}
```

Comment: i've tried your code and the login is working but the problem now is that when i'm logged in and i tried to type in the url the sample.php it redirect me to the signin page..by the way my sample.php is where my form for login is.

Answer (score 0):

Change last code block as-
    if(!isset($_SESSION["Survey_id"])) {
         header("Location:login.php");
    }

As session variable is not set then redirect to login.php.

Comment: can please give me a sample login?